# How does the Object constructor have access to a .toString() method?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am experimenting with the `Object.prototype.toString()` method. I understand that created objects are [[Prototype]] linked to the `Object.prototype` object, therefore can access this method. However, calling `Object.toString()` also works. I'm wondering where the Object constructor can access this method when it doesn't have a direct method `.toString()` on itself. Is the Object constructor [[Prototype]] linked to its own prototype object?

```
Object.toString() // "function Object() { [native code] }"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is a `Function` which is an `object`.

It's confusing, but because the Object constructor is a function it shares the common Object.prototype methods, and when you run `toString` on a function, typically it'll return the function's code.

Comment: So to clarify, by being a function (the Object constructor) it is able to access the methods in `Function.prototype`. Yet, also, `Function.prototype` is [[Prototype]] linked to `Object.prototype`, so then the Object constructor has access to its own prototype object. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the case.